# Using an N type device as a high sided switch

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, switching

The attached circuit is a battery switching device that, at regular intervals, flips a relay and so switches which of two batteries is powering a load.

As an already built device, it seems to work ok in this configuration although the transistors are apparently acting as a high-side switch as they are positioned between the 12V supply, from one of the batteries depending on which way the relay is set, and the load. I plan to build a PCB for this module and want to get the right configuration.

I was under the impression that this type of arrangement needed a PNP set up, unless perhaps it works but is not very efficient due to the base not being switched on fully? The base voltage here is the same as that applied to the collector and other forum posts indicate that the base needs a higher voltage than that being switched.

So my queries are, firstly is it ok in my context to use an N type BJT (TIP3055 or similar) as a high-sided switch? If so are there any issues around the base voltage required to turn it on fully?

Secondly, could I replace the N channel BJTs with N type FETs, such as the FCPF260N60E, and will it work equally well? Or would the issue of adequate Gate voltage to turn it on fully be a problem and require additional components?

Thanks

[image: Battery Swapper]

Comment: Those are NPN bipolar junction transistors (BJTs.)  "N channel" applies to MOSFETs, not BJT.

Comment: Why does it use a relay and the TIP-3055 transistors?  Is the relay rated for really low current or something?

Comment: Is that a latching relay?

Comment: If your main circuit ever has a short circuit, the TIP-3055 transistors are toast.

Comment: As you mention without voltage higher than collector/drain there will be a drop on switches. Why don't you use PNP? Or move switches to low-side.

Comment: Simple trick is adding one 9V battery for supplying gates of N-ch. It will last a years.

Comment: Yes it uses NPN so I’m asking if I should use PNP instead or is the issue of base voltage not so relevant when using. BJT? The relay takes a small current to flip which transistor is receiving a voltage at it base so ample capacity in that device. I have a fuse in the main circuit that trips at 5A and the main circuit is only taking about 3A.

Comment: I’m using NPN at the moment as that is how it was designed by someone else and it does work. What I’m asking is whether it is working efficiently and, if there is a v drop across the BJT, then that will just show in the voltage going to the main circuit and is not critical. Perhaps this is why it still works ok. But if I want to switch to FETs am I right in thinking that I will definitely need to change to P channel devices and add a pull up resistor for the gates? Or maybe it will still work like the BJTs do and I will just loose 0.6V or whatever going to my main circuit?

Comment: adding a 9V battery is a good idea but I don't have the space for it.